# Request API com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-service, api, web-scraping

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web em que o objetivo será utilizar uma API para fazer apenas a listagem de alguma informação (GET) e para isso gostaria de utilizar apenas javaScript e html.

A API é esta: https://www.football-data.org/documentation/ e possui key(headers).

```js
const app = document.getElementById('root');

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.appendChild(container);


var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);
request.onload = function() {

  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(movie => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.textContent = movie.title;

      const p = document.createElement('p');
      movie.description = movie.description.substring(0, 40);
      p.textContent = `${movie.description}...`;

      container.appendChild(card);
      card.appendChild(h1);
      card.appendChild(p);
    });
  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
    errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
    app.appendChild(errorMessage);
  }
}

request.send();
```

```css
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #666;
    background: #F6F6F6;
}

#root {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #96af9f 0%, #9fc5a7 100%);
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    max-width: 8%;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 8px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    transform: translate3D(0, -2px, 0);
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #9fc5a7;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
    .card {
        flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 2rem);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .card {
        flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 2rem);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Football stats</title>
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="root">
    <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="active"href="index.html">Today Matches</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Portuguese League</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A ideia principal é fazer uma listagem dos jogos do dia com o nome do campeonato e o respectivo jogo.

Na documentação tem este exemplo de request em javascript/jquery:

$.ajax({

headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' },

url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v2/matches?status='LIVE',

dataType: 'json',

type: 'GET',

}).done(function(response) {

// do something with the response, e.g. isolate the id of a linked resource

console.log(response);

});

**A dúvida é como poderei fazer uma coneccao a uma api com headers?**

Comment: Esse *headers* que comenta são os cabeçalhos da requisição?

Comment: Já tentou usar o método [`setRequestHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader())?

Answer (score 3):

Substitua

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);
request.onload = function() {
```

Por

```
fetch('url da api', { headers:{ //seus headers } })
.then(retorno =>{ 
 //faz sua tratativa do retorno aqui.
 })
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Onde está o console log você pode fazer a sua função com todo o resto.

Aproveite e de uma lida na documentação do fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch